# How to display only the 0th index data in my webpage using Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios"
import '../App.css';
import ProgressBarForCO from "../progress bar/ProgressBarForCO"
import ProgressBarForNO from "../progr`your text`ess bar/ProgressBarForNO";
import ProgressBarForNO2 from "../progress bar/ProgressBarForNO2";
import ProgressBarForSO2 from "../progress bar/ProgressBarForSO2";

export default function Home() {

    const [airData, setAirData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(
        () => {
            loadAirData();
        }, []
    );
    
    const loadAirData = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/AirData");
        setAirData(result.data);
    
    }
    
    return (
    
        <div >
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='py-4'>
                    {
                        airData.map((data) => (
                            <h1 style={{
                                color: 'white',
                                fontSize: '30px'
                            }}>
                                Data Received Time : {data.timeStamp}
                            </h1>
                        ))}
    
                </div>
                <div className="containerBox" style={{ marginTop: '25px' }}>
    
                    {
                        airData.map((data) => (
                            <>
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>Carbon Monoxide </p>
                                        <div style={{
                                            width: '100px',
                                            display: 'block',
                                            marginLeft: 'auto',
                                            marginRight: 'auto'
                                        }}>
                                            <ProgressBarForCO score={data.co} /></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ))}
                    {
                        airData.map((data) => (
                            <>
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>Nitric oxide </p>
                                        <div style={{
                                            width: '100px',
                                            display: 'block',
                                            marginLeft: 'auto',
                                            marginRight: 'auto'
                                        }}>
                                            <ProgressBarForNO score={data.no} /></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ))}
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div className="containerBox">
                    {
                        airData.map((data) => (
                            <>
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>Nitrogen dioxide</p>
                                        <div style={{
                                            width: '100px',
                                            display: 'block',
                                            marginLeft: 'auto',
                                            marginRight: 'auto'
                                        }}>
                                            <ProgressBarForNO2 score={data.no2} /></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ))}
                    {
                        airData.map((data) => (
                            <>
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>Sulphur dioxide </p>
                                        <div style={{
                                            width: '100px',
                                            display: 'block',
                                            marginLeft: 'auto',
                                            marginRight: 'auto'
                                        }}>
                                            <ProgressBarForSO2 score={data.so2} /></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ))}
    
                </div>
                <ul className="final">
                    <li style={{ color: '#66FF00' }}>Excellent</li>
                    <li style={{ color: '#90EE90' }}>Good</li>
                    <li style={{ color: 'yellow' }}>Lightly polluted</li>
                    <li style={{ color: '#FFBF00' }}>Heavily polluted</li>
                    <li style={{ color: 'red' }}>Severely polluted</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

I tried setting the "setAirData(result.data[0]". But it is displaying an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the compiler is complaining that `airData.map` is not a function. that means that `airData` is not an array :

```
const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/AirData");
console.log(result.data) // <-- add this line
setAirData(result.data);
```

Most probably here that your endpoint is returning un object as `result.data` not an `array`

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping your `airData` in the component render, therefore, it has to be an array. When you set it to be `results.data[0]`, `airData` is converted to an object and it cannot be mapped.

You can do `setAirData([results.data[0]])` instead and it will set the value to be an array with only the first element, and it will render just fine.

Answer (score 0):

the `airdata` is not an array.

```
setAirData([results.data[0]])
```